# Make my own answers more visible to me

Tags: feature-request

When I google a question, and end up on a Stack Overflow page with many answers, I might easily waste time viewing the top couple of answers, when I have previously answered this exact question long ago with what I feel is a much better answer for my purposes. Maybe I answered it long after an accepted answer was already picked.

When I realize that I have previously answered it, I feel time has been wasted and might use my own answer.

I think if you have previously answered a question, your answer should either be at the top of the page (for you only of course), or at least there should be a strong indicator above the fold that you have previously answered this question.

Examples:

- [How to position one element relative to another with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158070/how-to-position-one-element-relative-to-another-with-jquery#comment491224_158176)
- [How to merge two arrays in JavaScript and de-duplicate items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript-and-de-duplicate-items)

Comment: This sounds like something that could/should be "fixed" with a user script.

Comment: welllllll... no offense meant, but the way to make your own answer more visible, would be to make it better than the other existing answers... there is a reason for the voting system.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Many old popular questions have many answers. If you answer it, it takes a long time to move up the ranks. If you answer, you probably feel your answer works best for you and makes sense for it to be most visible for you.

Comment: @NathanOliver Fair enough, I suppose I could add some custom js through browser plugin. I already do it for css. Good idea.

Comment: @Andrew I believe we do not share an understanding on the target of answers. When I post an answer, it doesn't have anything to do about me, it's about the question, and wether or not the angle from which I approach the problem has been adressed in the other answers. In my opinion, "works best for me" has nothing to do with anything in this site apart from the vote I cast on a post.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Actually the entire point of the site is to provide answers to questions and hopefully provide the best available answer to the visitor of the site. If you have answered the question previously, the best available answer will probably be your answer, and not the most up-voted one.

Comment: I disagree with that notion. It's more likely that the most upvoted one would be the one that is better, even more so than the one you wrote yourself.

Comment: @KevinB Not if you didn't answer the question simultaneously. Answer any old question with an updated clean answer and your answer is likely the best answer now.

Comment: Keep in mind StackOverflow lets you Ask and answer your own question simultaneously. It encourages you to use the site to answer your own problems, in theory for use as your own reference notes, and to share with others. Kind of really makes sense to boost your own answer to the top when considering this.

Comment: I wouldn't bet on that either. You, being the author of said answer, may believe that your answer is better, but that's solely because you wrote it. If you didn't think it were better you wouldn't have posted it.

Comment: Note that you can easily search questions you were involved in first, by searching in Stack Overflow and starting your search with `user:youruserid` (`user:3093731` in your case). I often use this when I think I've answered a question before.

Comment: There are far easier ways to find your own answers.  `user:me is:answer log a big number`

Comment: Thanks for inputs.., i suppose only helpful for people with tendancy to answer older questions that none of the answers suited their needs, and then later referenced those same questions.

Comment: somewhat related: [When there are many answers already, help me check that mine won't repeat others](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2562/168)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

A few people suggested that I could just implement my own script.

Using a javascript injector extension for chrome, added this js for stackoverflow.com, solves my problem nicely, but only so long as my answer is on the first page of answers.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        //moves my own answers to the top
        var el = $('div.user-details').find('a[href="/users/3093731/andrew"]');
        if(el.length){
            el.closest('div.answer').css('border', '2px solid green');
            $('#answers').prepend(el.closest('div.answer'));
        }

        //moves answers I've up-voted to the top
        var el = $('.js-vote-up-btn.fc-theme-primary');
        if(el.length){
            el.closest('div.answer').css('border', '2px solid green');
            $('#answers').prepend(el.closest('div.answer'));
        }
    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: *covers ears, eyes while chanting "la la la can't hear you"*

Answer (score 5):

I don't think that it would be a good idea to spend dev time doing this.

It would "benefit" only users who:

- Answer questions with many answers and
- Want to know the answer to those *same* questions they've already answered later (rare) and
- Forget that they've answered that question and don't remember when they visit it and
- Have written a sufficiently in depth and decent answer that they think they want their exact answer

This is a very narrow use case, and also bypassing the voting system. I can't see this brining much use.

You could probably make a Tamper/Greasemonkey Userscript for that very easily, though.